# Visual studio complete removal

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2012

I have been given a network path by my company's Admin team to install every software . This path is accessible by request only . I dont know some how I have corrupted my Visual studio 2013 , IIS , Sql server 2012 and i need to reinstall everything . When I try to remove VS 2013 from the network path folder which is been given by my admin team , i can see that everything related to Visual studio is still there in machine . So after googling , i cam eto know that I have to run this installer by force command to be run on command prompt i.e. < Installation / Set up directory >vs_ultimate.exe /uninstall /force command . Now my question is how can I run this command on a folder ( \100.00.00.123\Softwares\Installers\VS_setup\VS_setup.exe  folder path .

Comment: run the installer again. there should be an option to remove the installation.

Comment: No there isnt any besides this now i am not able to create any website